# Regex: match any string between date and a colon

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have this string `[14:42:49] Any Nick Name: Message bla bla` and the only thing I want is  `Any Nick Name`.

I was never really good at regex and I can't remember how to get a specific part of the result. I came this far: `/\[([0-9]{2}(:|\])){3} (.+):/g` resulting in `[14:42:49] Any Nick Name:`.

Well sure I could remove the last and first part with substr and so on, but isn't there an easier way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp is almost correct.

```
var regexp = /^\[\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\] (.+):/;
```

This matches `[xx:xx:xx] something:` with `x` being digits. The `^` means that the string should start there, and `\d` means a digit. The `g` flag doesn't add anything here.

Use `.exec`, and use `[1]` to get the first group (the characters matched inside the parens):

```
regexp.exec("[14:42:49] Any Nick Name: Message bla bla")[1];
// "Any Nick Name"
```

Comment: Thanks it's actually [3] for me since the result is `[14:42:49] Any Nick Name:, 49], ], Any Nick Name`. Is there no way to access groups with the match() function ?

Comment: @elias94xx You can access it via RegExp.$1 (for the first captured group and $2 $3 and so on)

Comment: @elias94: `str.match(regexp)` gives two elements, with the second being the one you wanted. I did change my regexp though, perhaps you're using the one I provided before my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the regex

```
/\[[^\]]+\]\s([^\:]+)/g

// test with
"[14:42:49] Any Nick Name: Message bla bla".match(/\[[^\]]+\]\s([^\:]+)/g); 

// "Any Nick Name"
console.log(RegExp.$1)
```

Comment: This matches `[not a date] blah blah:`.

Comment: @dbaupp I only got "Any Nick Name".

Comment: the question is asking for matching a specific format (`[xx:xx:xx] nickname: ...`), but this will match anything with a non-empty pair of square brackets (so doesn't completely fulfil the requirements).

Comment: @dbaupp Did you try it? or just answer without testing it.

Comment: Yes: your regex matches anything with square brackets. Like `[a] text` (prints `text`), or `[12:34:56] Nickname: text` (prints `Nickname`) or `[3743] 123456` (prints `123456`). So it does match the OP's request, but it matches other strings as well. (Just like welldan97 and Robbie's answers too).(Apologies if I seemed confrontational :( )

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you want is `Any Nick Name`, you can use this:

```
^.*?\] (.*?):
```

Demo: http://regexr.com?30btc (hover on each selection to see the matched group)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a positive lookbehind for the `]` (including the space) like this:

```
(?<=]\s)[\w\s]+
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support those.